# Dbeaver Stopped showing error in lower right of app

Tags: runtime-error, dbeaver

Dbeaver 21.1.5 shows the error messages in the lower right hand corner instead of in results now. Is there a way to fix this? To put them in the middle and not the code without any information about error?